unable to resolve timestamp in android framestats data
does anyone has any idea about framestats https://developer.android.com/tools/dumpsys#ui
Question - While running framestats command I am getting some wierd timestamps
Example
Flags,IntendedVsync,Vsync,OldestInputEvent,NewestInputEvent,HandleInputStart,AnimationStart,PerformTraversalsStart,DrawStart,SyncQueued,SyncStart,IssueDrawCommandsStart,SwapBuffers,FrameCompleted,DequeueBufferDuration,QueueBufferDuration,GpuCompleted,
1,146696088396343,146696571729686,9223372036854775807,0,146696581891073,146696581894611,146696581897880,146697072749611,146697073366726,146697078783572,146697079121803,146697080224149,146697082513226,0,524962,0,
1,146698922377875,146698922377875,9223372036854775807,0,146698923674840,146698923677994,146698923976609,146698949996725,146698950291379,146698950697879,146698950903148,146698957816571,146698961607994,3572884,579693,0,
1,146698938951344,146698938951344,9223372036854775807,0,146698953406302,146698953410763,146698954719917,146698973898109,146698974007302,146698974468955,146698975846379,146698985501379,146698989020840,5225577,1202039,0,
if you take example of this then 146696088396343ns is pointing to 2nd Jan 1970.
I am expecting if I convert 146696088396343ns timestamp. I should get some valid date

These timestamps are not meant to be directly converted to dates. They're MONOTONIC system clock data  (see source code here). As reported in the document, this type of timestamp is recommended to calculate elapsed times.
For instance, if you have this profile data for rendering a frame:
Flags,IntendedVsync,Vsync,OldestInputEvent,NewestInputEvent,HandleInputStart,AnimationStart,PerformTraversalsStart,DrawStart,SyncQueued,SyncStart,IssueDrawCommandsStart,SwapBuffers,FrameCompleted,DequeueBufferDuration,QueueBufferDuration,GpuCompleted,
0,4947428577884,4947428577884,4947410644000,4947417134500,4947430768177,4947432698385,4947434430635,4947434503677,4947436475094,4947436682677,4947436721510,4947437213719,4947440847094,74292,192541,4947440671302,

you can calculate the difference between GpuCompleted and IntendedVsync timestamps (4947440671302 - 4947428577884) and convert the result (12093418) to milliseconds (12.09ms). As you can see 12ms is below the 16ms threshold therefore the time taken to render the frame is considered ok and it is not a sign of lagging.
Even though it is a bit old, this additional document should provide you more detailed explanations of the meaning of the other fields in the profile data.
Happy profiling!

Thanks for the answer.
The usecase - I have some events from the app with timestamp. And I want to visualize the framestats data with those events. i.e.
Can I see framestats data within two events?

The original question you posted is related to the meaning of the timestamps in the profile data. If you feel that the answer above does help you, then please consider to upvote or accept it. For the second question, it is more appropriate to create a new question in StackOverflow. thanks

Probably not the answer you are looking for but https://medium.com/@dtmilano/analyzing-android-ui-performance-52beb577c421 could help you getting the stats
